# STM32 How do I generate random hex for creating keys for ECC algorithm?

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

How do I create a random hex for keys to implement ECDH algorithm for STM32G4. I also need to convert random hex in the format like below

```
random_hex = 708309a7449e156b0db70e5b52e606c7e094ed676ce8953bf6c14757c826f590 

key_array[] =
{ 0x70, 0x83, 0x09, 0xa7, 0x44, 0x9e, 0x15, 0x6b, 0x0d, 0xb7, 0x0e, 0x5b, 0x52, 0xe6, 0x06, 0xc7,
  0xe0, 0x94, 0xed, 0x67, 0x6c, 0xe8, 0x95, 0x3b, 0xf6, 0xc1, 0x47, 0x57, 0xc8, 0x26, 0xf5, 0x90}
```

Comment: Just an idea: you could start with reading some timer counter.

Comment: STM32G4 devices have a hardware random number generator. e.g. see section 26 of the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0440-stm32g4-series-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf). There will be an easy to use HAL interface to it.

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. 1) How to generate random numbers at run-time. 2) How to convert a string into a C byte array at compile-time. It would be easier to answer if you actually split this into two separate questions.

Comment: @pmacfarlane - thanks, I looked at HAL interface but i am not sure if it would generate random numbers in hex format.

Comment: A number is a number. It exists independently of how you want to display it. Your question is becoming even more unclear. What do you actually want to achieve? You can use things like `sprintf()` if you want to convert a number into ASCII text.